# Ajax not working in IE8 on dropdown but it's working fine in other browsers

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

My ajax code is working fine in other browsers but in IE it's not working well.

It's creating XMLHTTPRequest but the value from my PHP script is only an empty list!

Here's my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getcity()
    {
        $('#stateerr').hide();
        state=document.getElementById("ddlstate").value;
       // alert(state);
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {
              alert('in this');
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          alert(xmlhttp);
          }
        else
          {
            alert('in that');
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("ddlcity").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
           alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
          }
          var str="getcity.php?q="+state;
         // alert(str);
        xmlhttp.open("GET",str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }



    function getlocation()
    {
        $('#cityerr').hide();
        city=document.getElementById("ddlcity").value;
        //alert(state);
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("ddllocality").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
           // alert('inhttpresponse');
            }
          }
          var str="getlocation.php?q="+city;
         // alert(str);
        xmlhttp.open("GET",str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Here's my HTML form:

```
<form name="search" action="search.php" method="GET" onsubmit="return searchCheck()">
<table width=100% >
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=3>
                    <div class="backgroundgif" id="backgroundgif" style="height:30px;width:100%">
                    <span style="font-size:15px; color:#CCFFFF;">
                    Search Property
                    </span>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Property For
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Rent <input type="checkbox" name="rentchkbox" id="rentchkbox" value="1" onclick="getRentPriceRange()"/>  
                        Sell<input type="checkbox" name="sellchkbox" id="sellchkbox" value="1"  onclick="getSellPriceRange()"/>      
                    </td>


                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Purpose
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="purpose">
                        <option>Family</option>
                        <option>Student</option>
                        <option>s</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Price range
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="ddlamount1" id="ddlamount1" onchange="hideerr()">
                            <option>select checkbox</option> 
                        </select>
                    </td>
                     <td><div id="ddlamount1err" style="display:none"><img src="IMAGES/errorsmall.png"/></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        State
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="ddlstate" id="ddlstate" onchange="getcity()">
                            <option>select state</option>
                            <option>MAHARASTRA</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><div id="stateerr" style="display:none"><img src="IMAGES/errorsmall.png"/></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        City
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="ddlcity" id="ddlcity" onchange="getlocation()">
                            <option>select city</option>
                            <option>PUNE</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><div id="cityerr" style="display:none"><img src="IMAGES/errorsmall.png"/></div></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Locality
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="ddllocality" id="ddllocality">
                            <option>Select Locality</option>
                            <option>indra nagar</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                       <input type="submit" value="Search">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </form>
```

And here's my PHP script.  The code gets cities from the state dropdown.

```
<?php
require_once('connection_class2.php');
$connection=new Dbconnection;
$query="select country_id from country where country_name='$_GET[q]'";
$result=$connection->select($query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($result))
{
 $country_id=$row->country_id;
}

$query1="select state_name from state where country_id='$country_id'";
$result1=$connection->select($query1);

echo '<option>';
echo 'select state';
echo '</option>';
while($rw=mysqli_fetch_object($result1))
{
 $state_name=$rw->state_name;
echo '<option>';
echo $state_name;
echo '</option>';
}
?>
```

There are other functions in the form for validation, but I have omitted them because they seem irrelevant.

Comment: Try adding different variable name inside two javascript functions which are named same as 'xmlhttp' . Also please tell whether the ajax call is initiated and what else happens?

Comment: this code is perfectly running in FF n Chrome but, it's only creating the problem in IE.n i have tried changing the name of variables but still it's not working!! n ajax call initiates if you'll put an alert in that response condition you'll get that it's returning response value but not showing in dropdown !

Answer (score 1):

The innerHTML option **wont work** for select element in IE..

So its better to create the whole select element with options from your php file and return them .

then have a div for placing the select box and use the normal innerHTML property to add the content.

Else

You have to add options using javascript and it differs for IE and others..
The following example adds an element dynamically to the select box..

```
function displayResult()
{
var x=document.getElementById("mySelect");
var option=document.createElement("option");
option.text="Kiwi";
try
  {
  // for IE earlier than version 8
  x.add(option,x.options[null]);
  }
catch (e)
  {
  x.add(option,null);
  }
}
```

I think u can use the first option and that would be easy..

Comment: hey! kvijayhari, i think i have got problem n that's, i'm alerting the xmlhttp.responseText in response condition n guess what! it's showing the values of cities in alert box in FF n chrome but in IE it's only showing the first option that is <option>select city</option> but in FF it's showing all values like <option>select city</option> <option>city1</option> <option>city2</option> n so on !! but the problem is the response i'm getting in only IE!!

Comment: if i'm making a div n creating whole select element still it's working fine in FF n Chrome but not working in IE again!! it's only showing "select city" like a label in place of dropdown!!

Comment: In your PHP file instead of creating only <option> , create such as this '<select><option>select city</option><option>city1</option></select>' and then have a div in html page, then in your ajax function get that div by using getElementByid and set using innerhtml.. Got clear? It should work..